# Intel server board boot menu

Tags: boot, usb, intel

I have a intel board SE7520BD2 with AMIBIOS 2003 with a raid controller SRCZCRX and I need to boot it from my pen drive.
As I have problems in the RAID disks it already booted once from my usb, but I need to boot it again and it always boot from disk. 
I already try F8 and F10 after RAID controller posts, but I still unable to boot from the usb pen drive.

How can I force booting from usb?

Another questions. It is a very old server and I lost bios password. 
How can I reset it?

Edit: I already found the answer to bios password in the documentation, but I still does not know how to force a boot menu to choose the right device.

Comment: Have you tried reading the docs that came with the board? They are also online....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the downvotes are because, as it states in our help page, that we expect those asking questions to have made some attempt at fixing their own problem before asking on here, you haven't even read the documentation - also here *IS* no SE7520DB22 board, did you mean SE7520BD2? if you did look in here http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/se7520bd2/sb/c51518007_se7520bd2_userguide.pdf